# Upgrade to Xubuntu 11.04 Breaks Wireless

Tags: 11.04, wireless, xubuntu

When I tried to connect at 2 different places. The little connection icon would circle forever before eventually prompting for password.

I have triple checked all network keys & then some.

Even with my home network I now have to revert to 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx (dual boot) or wired Ethernet.

Not even sure where to start trouble shooting TBH?

My card is a Edimax EW-7108PCg PCMCIA card which I bought for it's out the box Linux compatibility.  Hardware is an IBM Thinkpad T21.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Delete the connection and redo it. Of course not sure it will work, but ........

Comment: All ready tried manually creating connection.